# How can I find the distribution of sample mean of Cauchy distribution?

Tags: distributions, mean, cauchy-distribution

Let $Y_1,...,Y_n \sim Cauchy(0,1), i,i,d.$

How can I find the distribution of $\bar{Y}$?

I know that $Y_1+Y_2\sim Cauchy(0,2)$ by some integration,

but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Doesn't what you know immediately imply $(Y_1+Y_2)/2$ has a Cauchy$(0,1)$ distribution?  Thus, you already have the answer for $n=2$.  Maybe the same kind of integration method you used will extend to larger $n$.